# Setting the content type in the response header from the view resolver not working

Tags: html, spring, mime-types

Please excuse if this is too naive, I am new to Spring.

I have a simple rest controller API which is sending the name of the view.

```js
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminWebUI(final Model model, final Locale locale) {
    return "index";
}
```

I am trying to set the content type in the response header as below, but this is not working. I am instead receiving the Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 in the response header.Something else is overriding here or this is not the right way to set the content type, please help.

```js
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        final InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        final int order = 1;
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setOrder(order);
        resolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }
```